# Assigning variable value for particular users in angular application

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I m developing the application based on roles using angular 4 and spring boot web services.As I am having two user i.e super admin and client admin. Super admin creating client admin and giving some permissions to him for accessing the application as well as super admin is setting one payment options for this client admin.
So for setting this payment options I am thinking to use Local storage for storing this variable value but as I am log out as Super admin and trying to logged in as client admin, this local storage gets refreshed I lost my variable. 
I am not getting way to do this variable passing from one user to another.
Can anyone please clear my doubts?

Comment: Can show us what you have tried so far (by showing some code) and most importantly, as Hrishikesh as mentioned, you should not store the payment options in the local storage,. You should store them in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand why you are setting the payment option for one particular client admin in browser local storage?

browser local storage should be used to maintain the user session through the state of an application.

if you want to set payment option for ay client admin created by super admin I think you should use API call to the server to store this option in the database and everytime client admin log's in check if payment option is available or no.

I think this would be easier to maintain user roles and their permission across all browser.

Comment: Is there any other option than creating field in database? Please suggest and thank you for your response.

Comment: it totally depends on your logic how you want to show and give permission please let me know in detail I can help you with more.

Comment: As my super admin creating client admin and doing all settings for him, super admin assigning the customized name for payment options like wallet or money Bank to each client admin. This customized name should be used display or visible to client admin when he will try to make payment instead of default name.

Comment: let's assume that every client admin will log in from a different machine and different browser. for this, you need to check one just one extra parameter from login response that what all permissions are given to this client admin. as your requirement is not related to only browser level but the user level as a user can log in from anywhere. but if you know that this particular permission is only for this client admin then you can directly add if-else statements in typescript but if it is not,  there is no alternative for your use case to work perfectly.